# Graphene and Hubbard model

Tags: condensed-matter, graphene

I am trying to understand the graphene Hamiltonian. As I see, the Hubbard model can be presented as follows

$$
\mathcal{H} = \sum_{i,j,\sigma} - t_{ij} \hat{c}^\dagger_{j,\sigma}\hat{c}_{i,\sigma} + h.c. + U \sum_i \hat{n}_{i\uparrow}\hat{n}_{i\downarrow},
$$
where we have kinetic and potential terms. I saw the graphene is well approximated only by the first term. I saw on Wikipedia, that $U=0$ means that we consider the Fermi gas.
So, do we assume in graphene that we consider Fermi gas or are there any other reasons that we consider only kinetic term?

Comment: The reason we can in many cases neglect interactions in solid state systems is a rather long story eventually resolved by [Fermi liquid theory](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevResearch.4.013119)